# Defining $H$ *magnetic field* in Magnetostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

This question is related to [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856562/term-cancelling-confusion-involving-a-triple-vector-product) in `math.SE`. I'm having troubles studying the "macroscopic" case for a magnetic potential vector and verifying what the Maxwell's equations yields.

Particularly I have

$$\vec{f} =\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{\nabla} \times \langle \vec{A}_M (\vec{x}) \rangle$$

where

$$ \langle \vec{A}_M(\vec{x})\rangle = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int d^3x' \cdot \frac{\vec{j}_c(\vec{x}') + \vec{J}_l (\vec{x}')}{\|\vec{x} - \vec{x}'\|}$$

I know:

$$\vec{f} = \vec{\nabla} (\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A}_M (\vec{x})) - (\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{\nabla}) \langle A_M\rangle$$

so it involves the integral of the laplacian of a $G_0$ [Green's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function). This is proportional to an impulse function and cancels the integral nicely. Anyways, I don't see well how the first term in $\vec{f}$ apparently vanishes.

$$\vec{f} = \vec{\nabla} (\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A}_M (\vec{x})) - (\vec{\nabla}^2) \langle A_M\rangle$$

$$\vec{f} = \vec{\nabla} (\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A}_M (\vec{x})) - \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \int d^3x' \cdot (\vec{j}_c(\vec{x}') + \vec{J}_l (\vec{x}')) (-4\pi \delta^3) $$

$$\rightarrow \vec{f} = \vec{\nabla} (\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A}_M (\vec{x})) + \mu_0 \cdot (\vec{j}_c(\vec{x}') + \vec{J}_l (\vec{x}'))$$

Checking my lecturer's notes he states that the grad(div(*)) term should cancel, assuming static currents and $\vec{0}$ current at $\partial V$. Then I checked Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics* textbook and I find

$$\nabla \times B = \frac{4\pi}{c} J + 4\pi \nabla \times M $$

Where $\vec{J}$ is the sum of both currents [**EDIT**: in Jackson "to obtain the macroscopic equivalent of the curl equation we calculate B (...) writing down (...) the total current ($J+J_M$) replacing $J$].
I recognize the first term emerging from the Laplacian of $G_0$ but what about $\nabla \times M$? What am I missing here?

**EDIT**:
-From Jackson:

> the conduction-current density is **J**, representing the actual transport of charge.

> atomic-current density **$J_a$** is representing the circulating currents inside atom or molecules.

> **M**$(x)$ is the macroscopic magnetization (magnetic moment per unit volume) defined by $$M = N \langle m_{mol} \rangle$$ where N is the number of molecules per unit volume.

> The vector potential can be written as: $$A(x) = \frac{1}{c} \int \frac{J(x') + c \nabla' \times M(x')}{|x-x'|} d^3x$$

In my lectures que redefined $\nabla \times M$ as $\vec{j}_c$ currents from atomic interaction. This coincides with $\langle A_M \rangle$ (ignoring the difference of unit systems).

Comment: Can explain what $j_c$ and $J_l$ are?  In Jackson ${\bf J}$ is only the transport current. The curl of ${\bf M}$ is the bound current,so I do not understand your statement that Jackson's ${\bf J}$ is "the sum of both currents"

Comment: @mikestone Hi, thanks for asking.

 $J_l$ corresponds to free currents on the conductor and $j_c$ are currents due to atomic / molecular charges. 

I tried to make this clearer editing the question. Hope it's better now.

Comment: So $J_l$ is Jackson's current ${\bf J}$ and $j_c=\nabla\times {\bf M}$ and   ${\bf H}\equiv {\bf B}- 4\pi {\bf M}$. Now what exactly is puzzling to you?

Comment: @mikestone exactly!  My problem arises when I try to compute the triple product. I don't see what happens with $\nabla (\nabla \cdot A_M)$. Here in the question, $\vec{f}$ should match Jackson's $\nabla \times B$, or at least this is what I expect.

Comment: Note that the formula you have written down for ${\bf A}$ is derived under the assumption that you have chosen the gauge in which $\nabla\cdot {\bf A}=0$.

Comment: Also what is $f$?

Comment: @mikestone omg now I understand... it's clearly the Gauge freedom (which I forgot). This way everything matches evenly. $f$ was the product, i.e., $\nabla \times B$